# What happens if your iPhone becomes damaged while preparing for AppleCare+ Repair?

Tags: iphone, sim, applecare

I recently cracked my iPhone XS's back camera. Since it is under AppleCare+ until early October, I paid $99 for an Express Replacement which requires that I mail the broken phone to them.

Unfortunately, when the replacement arrived, I had to switch the SIM card to the replacement, but the SIM card mechanism became damaged on the old phone while i was doing so. I do not believe I did anything wrong at all, it just wont let the tray back into the phone.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Should I contact Apple about it in advance and risk losing the right to my $99 claim or should I mail it in anyway and hope for the best? I believe it is a design flaw in the SIM tray that such a thing can happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would send it in, protect it as best you can - write a short note, I tried to get the SIM out, that didn’t go well, please help.

Send it off. If they call you and requote, you can decide if you pay more. If they fix it all, you’re set.

If you can’t write a short note, maybe just send it, but I would expect they’ll wonder more if it comes in shape not the same.

If you really are concerned, maybe get photos and call - but I’m guessing Apple will say send it in so we can look at it.